# C++ class instances which reference to each other

Tags: c++

It is possible to make circular references from class A to class B and vica-versa using forward declarations

```
class class_a;
class class_b;

class class_a {
    class_a(class_b& arg) : ref_to_b(arg){}; // constructor
    class_b& ref_to_b;
};

class class_b {
    class_b(class_a& arg) : ref_to_a(arg){}; // constructor
    class_a& ref_to_a;
};
```

How to create instances of such classes?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but the program will be ill-formed. Is it just out of curiosity or a real problem?

Comment: Assume you have a driver class and a handler class.
Driver should call handler's callbacks, and handle should call driver's methods

Comment: Use pointers and subscribe/unsubscribe ideoms.

Comment: Yeah, this is simple, but what about binding two classes in constructors? Constructors can be made constexpr and binding may happen at compile-time

Comment: If the two classes _must_ reference instances of one another (and non-rebindable), why do they need to be separate classes at all?

Comment: I mean what you want is possible, but effectively the class objects would be seriously limited in their normal use as class objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At global scope you can declare the classes before initializing them to obtain references:

```
extern class_a a;
extern class_b b;

class_a a{b};
class_b b{a};
```

And now that we have those we can use placement new to create more such pairs:

```
auto a2 = new class_a(a);
auto b2 = new class_b{a2};
a2 = new(a2) class_a{b2};
```

Now a2 and b2 point to another pair of such class objects.

However, I doubt that this is useful in practice.

Comment: This question is a prereq for another one.
Can this be done with templates?

Comment: May be you can answer this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74041423/c-tamplate-class-instances-which-reference-to-each-other